# Update column with +1 increment based on columns with duplicate value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with 3 columns (`itemid`, `altid`, `counter`)

I am having a difficult time looping through each row to update the `counter` column based on the number of duplicate `itemid`'s.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
itemid | altid | counter
1        30      1
1        31      2
1        37      3
5        53      1
5        54      2
6        112     1
6        113     2
6        114     3
6        115     4
```

Notice where the `itemid` is duplicated, the `counter` is incrementing +1.

The list goes on about 2500 rows. My `counter` column is empty. I have had no luck with the increment inside a while loop to update in php because I don't know how to detect that duplicate value (or checking that previous value).

This is all I have right now (doesn't work):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$itemid = $row['itemid'];
$i=1;
    if($row['itemid']!=$itemid){
    $i=1;
    }
$id = $row['id'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET counter='$i' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
$i++;
}
```

I searched and haven't found much to help accomplish this. Any help, or push in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What about `UPDATE table SET var=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ...)`?

Comment: I'm not sure i follow... How would I increment +1 on those duplicate values in the itemid column?

Comment: What's the point of your counter column? (ie, why have that vs the standard SQL-ish way of getting this data, `SELECT itemid, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY itemid`)

Comment: @Kolink was able to provide the solution I was looking for below.

Comment: Still would be useful to understand why you need to do that.

Comment: @James - I have a database of images that I have to rename from an old id based name to a new name such as alt1, alt2, alt3.jpg etc. All the data I had came from multiple databases and this is one of my final steps in renaming my images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this MySQL:

```
SET @pos=0, @last=0;
UPDATE `table` SET `counter`=(
    @pos:=if(
        @last=`itemid`,
        @pos+1,
        (@last:=`itemid`) and 1
    )
) ORDER BY `itemid` ASC;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking to accomplish. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a command especially for this (only in MySQL): [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)